# Whats the name of this sort of matrix

Tags: matrices, terminology

What the name of such a matrix

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 5 & 10 \\ 3 & 4 & 7 & 12 \\ 6 & 8 & 9 & 14 \\ 11 & 13 & 15 & 16\\ \end{pmatrix}

Its properties are:

1. North-west to South East diagonals are squares.
2. $\text{Matrix}[i][j] + 1 = \text{Matrix}[j][i]$ for each $i < j $.

Comment: No *every* sort of matrix has an established name...

Comment: It is a square matrix. It is an integer matrix. It is neither a symmetric matrix nor an antisymmetric matrix. What are you going for here?

Comment: The 17 looks 'out of place' to me , I would expect 12 in that position. :)

Comment: Maybe call it a "gnomen" matrix: Gnomens are the L shaped pieces which are of sizes 1,3,5,etc, and your matrix has placed the positive integers in this one gnomen at a time, each gnomen winding up with the square number [1+3+5=9, etc] on the diagonal, otherwise zig-zag top/bottom of gnomen in between.